# Joining dataframes to replace values

Tags: r, join

I am in the process of writing a large piece of code with test data. At this moment I have these two dataframes:

```
> abc
  BLOCK start end
1    B1     1   3
2    B2     4   6
3    B3     7   9
4    B4    10  12
> def
   V1 V2 V3 V4
r1 B1 B2 B3 B4
r2 B1 B2 B4 B3
r3 B1 B3 B4 B2
r4 B2 B3 B4 B1
>
```

The first dataframe, `abc`, contains the values of the BLOCK categorical variables. For example, B1 starts at 1 and ends with 3 (i.e. 1:3 or 1, 2, 3).

My goal is to expand out the `abc` dataframe, to the full range of values and then join it with the `def` dataframe. I've made many attempts with join, merge and different formats but I am not managing to succeed. Any help would be much appreciated.

The desired output is as follows:

```
1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9   10  11  12
1   2   3   4   5   6   10  11  12  7   8   9
1   2   3   7   8   9   10  11  12  4   5   6
4   5   6   7   8   9   10  11  12  1   2   3
```

Comment: Is the naive way, with two loops over rows and columns of `def`, constructing the output a row at a time, too slow?

Answer (score 1):

Build from parts. First a function to generate the sequence given a block code and the block definitions:

```
> seqB
function(B,abc){b = abc[abc$BLOCK==as.character(B),];seq(b$start, b$end)}
> seqB("B2",abc)
[1] 4 5 6
```

Then a function to create the Nth row of the output given the row number, block definitions, and the output row block sequence:

```
> rowN
function(N,def,abc){do.call(c,lapply(def[N,],seqB,abc=abc))}

> rowN(3,def,abc)
V11 V12 V13 V21 V22 V23 V31 V32 V33 V41 V42 V43 
  1   2   3   7   8   9  10  11  12   4   5   6
```

Finally, apply that Nrow times and rbind everything up to make the output:

```
> do.call(rbind,lapply(1:nrow(def),rowN,def=def,abc=abc))
     V11 V12 V13 V21 V22 V23 V31 V32 V33 V41 V42 V43
[1,]   1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9  10  11  12
[2,]   1   2   3   4   5   6  10  11  12   7   8   9
[3,]   1   2   3   7   8   9  10  11  12   4   5   6
[4,]   4   5   6   7   8   9  10  11  12   1   2   3
```

I suspect you could do this by writing `def` out in a long form, joining to a wide version of `abc` with expanded sequences, then extracting all the numbers and rearranging in a matrix of the right number of rows and columns, but I'm not sure it'd be faster.

Answer (score 0):

A different approach from what @Spacedman suggested.

First lets define the blocks,

```
crt_Block <- paste0(abc$BLOCK,"<- seq(",abc$start,",",abc$end,")" )
for(i in 1:length(crt_Block) ) eval(parse(text = crt_Block[i]) )
```

Next, I collapse the def matrix into a vector by rows, replacing the blocks with their numerical values and construct back the matrix.

```
v <- as.vector(t(def))
vec <- eval(parse(text = paste0("c(", paste(v,collapse=","),")")))
matrix(vec,byrow = T, ncol=3*ncol(def) )

     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7] [,8] [,9] [,10] [,11] [,12]
[1,]    1    2    3    4    5    6    7    8    9    10    11    12
[2,]    1    2    3    4    5    6   10   11   12     7     8     9
[3,]    1    2    3    7    8    9   10   11   12     4     5     6
[4,]    4    5    6    7    8    9   10   11   12     1     2     3
```